# How to replace Iterables.filter() with Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava

I'm trying to migrate from Guava to Java 8 Streams, but can't figure out how to deal with iterables. Here is my code, to remove empty strings from the iterable:

```
Iterable<String> list = Iterables.filter(
  raw, // it's Iterable<String>
  new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String text) {
      return !text.isEmpty();
    }
  }
);
```

Pay attention, it's an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), not a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). It may potentially contain an *unlimited* amount of items, I can't load it all into memory. What's my Java 8 alternative?

BTW, with Lamba this code will look even shorter:

```
Iterable<String> list = Iterables.filter(
  raw, item -> !item.isEmpty()
);
```

Comment: What type is `raw`?

Comment: Which version of Guava are you on? Or do you not want to use Guava at all?

Comment: @shmosel I want to get rid of Guava and migrate to Java 8 Streams, if that's possible at all. Maybe it's not. That's why asking here.

Comment: It's definitely not possible to replace all of Guava's utilities with streams, but you can replace this specific feature, as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can implement `Iterable` as a functional interface using `Stream.iterator()`:

```
Iterable<String> list = () -> StreamSupport.stream(raw.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(text -> !text.isEmpty())
        .iterator();
```

Comment: `iterator()` returns an instance of `Iterator`, not `Iterable`

Comment: @yegor256 Read it more carefully. Or try it out.

Comment: got it, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewTobilko OP indicated it could be an infinite stream. Either way, using a collector would be a performance cost.

Comment: It's not clear that there's any advantage to doing this vs. just using `Iterables.filter` to begin with, since this is just a re-implementation of `Iterables.filter` that happens to use a `Stream` under the hood. (Well, ok, if this is the _only_ thing you're doing with Guava and you see it as a big advantage to not use Guava at all, then I guess there's that...). But that's more an issue with what the OP is asking for than with the answer.

Comment: @ColinD It's quite clear when you consider that OP is "trying to migrate from Guava to Java 8 Streams".

Comment: @shmosel: Not taking issue with your answer... what people think they want to do isn't always necessarily a great idea though. Edit: Note, I do think that there are a lot of cases where migrating from Guava to Streams is a good idea... the Stream APIs are great, and we generally recommend them. But this specific case  (`Iterable` -> `Iterable` filtering) is something than isn't covered directly by them and there's a clear loss in readability here, in my opinion.

Comment: @ColinD OP's case happens to be covered by `Iterables.filter()`, but it's easy to imagine a case where one might need to chain multiple operations, like `filter()` and `transform()`. Sure, it's still possible with nested views or with `FluentIterable`, but I think it can be argued that using streams is more idiomatic in Java 8, even with my somewhat unusual workaround.